# Is it necessary to declare the 'internet client' capability if the only network usage is for the windows store?

Tags: .net, client, capability, windows-store

If a windows store app does not access the network, except to query the windows store to see if a feature has been purchased, is it necessary to declare the 'internet client' capability?

I'd like to avoid declaring capabilities I don't need. Also, it would remove the requirement that the app reference a privacy policy. (Since we couldn't transmit the data even if we collected it, there's not much point.)

Comment: Were you able to avoid it, then?

Comment: @Lohoris No, I wasn't able to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I may have misunderstood your question at first. If you are only using the built-in calls to check for features, you shouldn't need the internet client capability. The licensing calls are done through the underlying API, as I understand it, and not through an internet client connection.

The easiest way to check is to build a new app package in release mode, then install it on your machine and run it outside of Visual Studio 2012. If it works there, you should be good. Though, you may want a privacy policy anyway that indicates that your application may occasionally query the Microsoft Store to identify what features have been purchased.

Original answer below left in tact incase it was helpful at all:

Peter is right. Your app simply won't be able to make any internet calls without including that capability in the manifest. Putting together a basic privacy policy is pretty trivial. Here's an example from a Community Megaphone app that one of the Microsoft guys made.

http://devhammer.net/privacy

Just explain in simple terms what your app needs the internet connection for, and whether it uses any private information. It's just a very basic statement of trust to let the user know why your app needs to be online.

Answer (score 0):

"InternetClient" capability provides outbound access to the Internet and public networks through the firewall.  Without that capability an application would not be able to access the Store through the firewall.